# How can i merge the return of two functions in php?

Tags: php

I have two function and need to merge the string that it returned if possible.

Here's my functions:

```
function qty($numbers) {
    $numbers = array($this->strips_qty, $this->lancet_qty, $this->battery_qty, 
                                                            $this->misc_qty);

    function qty($numbers) {
        foreach ($numbers as $stock) {
            if ($stock)
                $result .= $stock . '<br>';
        }
        return $result;
    }

    if ($result = qty($numbers))
        return '(' . $result . ')';
}

function parts_requested($params) {
    $params = array($this->meter, $this->strips, $this->lancets, $this->control, 
                                        $this->ld, $this->battery, $this->misc);

    function parts_requested($params) {
        foreach ($params as $part) {
            if ($part)
                $result .= $part . ',';
        }
        return $result;
    }

    if ($result = parts_requested($params))
        return 'OK TO SEND: ' . $result;
}
```

where it says OK TO SEND... i would like to merge the result from the qty() into the return on the parts_requested() right after the words OK TO SEND.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This could probably be done outside of these two functions... or within a third function, if you'd like *(by using return values and passing the values from function to function.)* :)

Comment: How would i go about that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if understand it well but i'll do it like this:

`return 'OK TO SEND: ' . $result . qty($numbers);`

Or you can do it with an array and the merge it outside:

```
$result = array();
$result[]= parts_requested($params);
$result[]= qty($numbers);
echo implode($result,'');
```

**Updated answer as requested**

Change the definition of the second function as:

```
function parts_requested($params, $numbers) {
```

Then at **part_requested** change the line where you add the comma to:

```
`$result .= qty($numbers) . $part . ',';`
```

But i don't see where numbers is being updated every time the loop repeats.

Comment: What do you mean didn't quite work? Can you put the output or what do you want?

Comment: OK TO SEND: 10CTNOVAMAX, 743014 < product numbers but no quantities. I would like it to be like so:  OK TO SEND: (5) 10CTNOVAMAX, (2) whatever product here.

Comment: above would be if 5qty was selected for 10CTNOVAMAX and 2 was selected for whatever other product. Hope that is more clear.

Comment: There's a mistake in the line if($result = qty($numbers)), shouldn't it be == instead = ?

Comment: Perhaps the second option will work better but i can't integrate it and get it to work inside of my existing functions.

Comment: How do you get the number at the second function? i understand, you need to call the first function to add it before the . ',' part

Comment: No, it's suppose to be = otherwise == breaks the loop

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31894/discussion-between-skatox-and-head-way)

Answer (score 0):

There are better solutions to what you're doing, but try something like this:

```
// example outputs
$parts = 'OK TO SEND: 10CTNOVAMAX,743014';
$quantities = '5<br>6<br>';

$parts = array_split($parts, ': ');
$parts = array_split($parts[1], ',');
$quantities = array_split($quantities, '<br>');

$result = 'OK TO SEND: ';

foreach($parts as $key->$value) {

    $result .= '('.$quantities[$key].') '.$value;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understood the question and why you have repeating functions, but it seems as simple as:

```
function qty($numbers) {
  $numbers = array($this->strips_qty, $this->lancet_qty, $this->battery_qty, 
                                                        $this->misc_qty);
  $result = '';

  function qty($numbers) {
    foreach ($numbers as $stock) {
        if ($stock)
            $result .= $stock . '<br>';
    }
    return $result;
  }

  if ($result = qty($numbers))
    return '(' . $result . ')';
}

function parts_requested($params, $numbers) {
  $params = array($this->meter, $this->strips, $this->lancets, $this->control, 
                                    $this->ld, $this->battery, $this->misc);

  $result = '';

  function parts_requested($params) {
    foreach ($params as $part) {
        if ($part)
            $result .= $part . ',';
    }
    return $result;
  }

  if ($result = parts_requested($params))
    return 'OK TO SEND: ' . qty($numbers) . $result;
}
```

Note that I also had to define `$result` at the beginning of each function and that you'd have to call your function like this: `parts_requested($params, $numbers);` and that function will call the other one and insert the results.